# Is this a Lie algebra homomorphism?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $g\in \mathrm{SL}(4, \mathbb{C})$ and $v, w\in \mathfrak{so}(4, \mathbb{C})$, i.e. $v^{T}+v =0$ and $w^{T}+w=0$. 
We can define an action of $\mathrm{SL}(4, \mathbb{C})$ on $\mathfrak{so}(4, \mathbb{C})$ as $g.v = gvg^{T}$, and we have a corresponding linear map $\phi_{g}:\mathfrak{so}(4, \mathbb{C})\to \mathfrak{so}(4, \mathbb{C})$. 
Is it true that $\phi_{g}$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, even if $g\not\in \mathrm{SO}(4, \mathbb{C})$? So I want to check whether 
$$
vw-wv = vg^{T}gw-wg^{T}gv
$$
is true for any $g\in \mathrm{SL}(4, \mathbb{C})$ and $v, w\in \mathfrak{so}(4, \mathbb{C})$. This seems false, but actually I hope this to be true. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed false.  For instance, consider
$$g=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\qquad
v=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\qquad
w=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then by my calculations, 
$$vw-wv=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
whereas 
$$vg^Tgw-wg^Tgv=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you... then I have to find a different way to solve my problem...